# How to add a black bar on top and bottom of a video screen with a watermark on it?

Tags: video, cmd, ffmpeg

I have this code to watermark my videos but I believe that the watermark may be distracting so I want to add black bars on top and on the bottom to place my watermark in, how could I do that? Here's my code for the watermarking of the video, I'm also appending an intro and outro to the presentation.

```
for %%I in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work\*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe
-y -i "%%I" -i white.png -i out1.ts -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw/6:ih/18[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-1,scale=hd720,setsar=1[vl];[2:v][2:a][vl][0:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -r 20 -c:v libx264 -ar 48000 "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nI.mp4"

pause
```

Comment: The very purpose of a watermark is to be distracting so that the user can't use the footage commercially, it's an extremely bad idea to do what you propose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
for %%I in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work\*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe
-y -i "%%I" -i white.png -i out1.ts -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw/6:ih/18[logo][0v];[0v]pad=iw:1.2*ih:0:(oh-ih)/2[0v]; [0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-1,scale=-2:720,setsar=1[vl];[2:v][v1]scale2ref[2v][vm];[2v]setsar=1,split[2va][2vb];[2va][2:a][vm][0:a][2vb][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -r 20 -c:v libx264 -ar 48000 "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nI.mp4"
```

The final video resolution will no longer have width 1280; height remains 720.